# Throw Error: XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected For_, expecting Order_ or Return_ or Stable_

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

Once run the below code in qconsole Marklogic, i am getting below error

> XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error,
>   unexpected For_, expecting Order_ or Return_ or Stable_

```
let $prices := fn:doc('/training/prices.xml')/prices
let $order := fn:doc('/training/order.xml')/order
where $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]
for $kk in $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]
return 
<item>
{$kk}
</item>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

No need for XQuery 3 for this. Just add an extra `return` between the `where` and the next `for`:

```
let $prices := fn:doc('/training/prices.xml')/prices
let $order := fn:doc('/training/order.xml')/order
where $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]
return
for $kk in $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]
return 
<item>
{$kk}
</item>
```

To follow Michael's excellent advice, and optimize to return full items, I'd flip around the XPath, and return order items directly. Something like:

```
let $prices := fn:doc('/training/prices.xml')/prices
let $order := fn:doc('/training/order.xml')/order
for $item in $order/item
where $prices/priceList/prod[@num = $item/@num]
return
    $item
```

Or even shorter:

```
let $prices := fn:doc('/training/prices.xml')/prices
let $order := fn:doc('/training/order.xml')/order
return
    $order/item[@num = $prices/priceList/prod/@num]
```

HTH!

Comment: Alternatively, just move the final "for" clause before the "where" clause.

Comment: How to apply all attributes on <item> element

I am doing like that but not working, please guide to me

<item>
{$order/item/@*}
</item>

Comment: No need to reconstruct the order items, just return them as-is. See edits above..

Comment: My expected output is, i want print the <prod> information under the <item> element with all <item> attribute, like that below:

<item dept="WMN" num="557" quantity="1" color="navy">
<prod num="557">
<price currency="USD">29.99</price>
<discount type="CLR">10.00</discount>
</prod>
</item>

Comment: Please open a new question. That gives more space to write what you'd like to achieve, and what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 1):

In XQuery 1.0, no further `for` clauses are allowed after a `where` clause. In Marklogic, you may need to prefix your query string with a 3.0 version declaration:

```
xquery version "3.0";
```

Comment: Thanks, problem in DATABASE server because that allow only "1.0", please see below

[1.0-ml] XDMP-XQUERYVERSION: (err:XQST0031) xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;3.0-ml&quot;;&#10;let $prices := fn:doc('/t...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>10600756150967848748</database>...</options>) -- XQuery version is not recognized: "3.0-ml" (must be "0.9-ml", "1.0" or "1.0-ml")

Comment: In that case, and for your specific query, an additional `return` after the `where` clause will do the job.